# What is the "pnctest" cookie used for?

Tags: cookies

I'm testing [guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) for session management in an Elixir app and I noticed the cookie `pcntest=1`. I googled it and saw the same key/value in the example code on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952338/how-to-delete-and-reset-a-cookie-in-javascript).

What does the `pnctest` cookie mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might stand for "pub nub cookie test". Used by PubNub, cookieTest func in https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.16.5.js.

Comment: Wow, I think that's it. Thanks for solving that mystery!